# Example of equicontinuous sequence of functions which is not convergent

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove there exits an equicontinuous sequence which is not pointwise convergent.
I have been working on it but unfortunately , I am not even near to find such sequence of functions.

Does someone have any idea about it?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $f_n(x) = n$.

Comment: Yes, this is nice , I did not even realize this works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For a bounded example, try $f_n(x) = (-1)^n$.